# Word for towering, but in the other direction

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I could be standing at the bottom of a canyon, and admiring a towering cliff face.

> I had slowly crept to the edge of the cliff and was now staring into a ____ abyss.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/47677/discussion-on-question-by-mark-qvist-word-for-towering-but-in-the-other-directi).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'd use the word **precipitous** here, and the collocation *precipitous drop* is well known, most dictionaries refer to the steepness involved but not the drop usually associated with the term.

[Collins Thesaurus of the English Language](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/precipitous) does clearly list this, however:

> **precipitous** adjective
>
> 1. sheer, high, steep, dizzy, abrupt, perpendicular, *falling sharply* ...

(emphasis mine)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest ***[yawning](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yawning)***:

> 1:  wide open :  cavernous *<a yawning hole> <yawning gaps in the plot>*
>   <sub>*from [M-W.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/yawning)*</sub>

another alternative would be ***gaping***:

> : wide open : very large  *<a gaping hole>*
>   <sub>*also from [M-W.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gaping)*</sub>

Yes, they really used 'hole' for both of their examples.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I offer ***bottomless***.

M-W:

> **[bottomless](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/bottomless)**
>   *adjective*
>
> **2a** :  extremely deep
>
> the killer threw the gun into what he thought was a *bottomless* pit

Answer (score 0):

How about *vertiginous*?

Wiktionary:

> [*vertiginous*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vertiginous): having an
>   aspect of great depth, drawing the eye to look downwards

Oxford Dictionaries:

> [*vertiginous*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/vertiginous):
>   extremely high or steep; *vertiginous drops to the valleys below*

This works nicely as the sense one would have opposite to "standing at the bottom of a canyon, and admiring a towering cliff face".

Addendum: Just noticed that @JohnFeltz mentioned this word in his comment on the question. John, my acknowledgment.